# Condtions for a stochastic process to be locally non-factorizable

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

Given a stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t\in I}$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with continuous sample paths supported on a prob. space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and such that each pair $(X_s, X_t)$, with $(s,t)\in \mathcal{I}:=\{(s',t')\in I^{\times 2}\mid s' < t' \}$, admits a continuous joint Lebesgue density $\chi_{s,t}\in C(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$.

Suppose that for each $(\emptyset\neq)\,U\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ open there is $\Omega_U\in\mathscr{F}$ with $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_U)>0$ as well as $(\emptyset\neq)\,I_U\subseteq I$ open such that

$$\tag{1}(X_t(\omega))_{t\in I_U}\subset U\qquad\text{for each }\quad  \omega\in\Omega_U.$$

We call a function $\chi\in C(U\times U)$ ($U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$) *factorizable* if $\chi\equiv\chi(x,y)=\chi_1(x)\cdot\chi_2(y)$ for some $\chi_1, \chi_2\in C(U)$.

**Question:** Under which 'minimal' additional assumptions can we infer that $X$ is *locally non-factorizable* in the sense that

$$\tag{2}\forall\, (\emptyset\neq)\,U \text{ open } \ : \ \exists\,(s,t)\in \mathcal{I} \ \quad \text{ such that }\quad \ \left.\chi_{s,t}\right|_{U^{\times 2}} \ \text{ is not factorizable}? $$

**Remark:** Condition (2) should hold for instance if $X$ is a (sufficiently regular) diffusion, as the joint density $\chi\equiv\chi_{s,t}$ then adheres to the boundary condition $\lim_{s\rightarrow t}\chi_{s,t}(x,y) = \delta(x-y)$ of the Kolmogorov equations associated to $X$.
Also, by the continuity of $X$, Kolmogorov's zero-one law implies that (2) holds for the fixed open set $U=\mathbb{R}^d$ (as otherwise each $X_t$ would be constant almost surely, defying the existence of $\chi_{s,t}$). Surely the regularity condition (2) will be satisfied under some more general circumstances..